# How to get 2d plot corresponding to two variables in a multi variable function?

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to get 2D plot of two variables in a multi functional function, using matplotlib. Let me introduce an example., Consider a four variable function `f(m,x,y,z)=m-(x**2)+(y**2)+(z**2)`. How to get a plot `m` verses `x`?

Comment: Proceed to https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Excuse me, i am new in programming. i didn't understand what you mean, pardon ?